# Schematic "materialDashboard" not found in collection "@angular/material"

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was trying to create a dashboard using the following command:

```
ng generate @angular/material:materialDashboard --name myDashboard
```

When I executed the command, it resulted in an error:

```
Schematic "materialDashboard" not found in collection
"@angular/material". Error: Schematic "materialDashboard" not found in
collection "@angular/material".
  at SchematicEngine.createSchematic (/Users/xyx/Desktop/Git/question-authoring-platform/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.js:155:23)
  at CollectionImpl.createSchematic (/Users/xyx/Desktop/Git/question-authoring-platform/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/collection.js:12:29)
  at Object.getSchematic (/Users/xyx/Desktop/Git/question-authoring-platform/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/schematics.js:36:23)
  at GenerateCommand.getOptions (/Users/xyx/Desktop/Git/question-authoring-platform/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/schematic-command.js:194:40)
  at GenerateCommand.<anonymous> (/Users/xyx/Desktop/Git/question-authoring-platform/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/generate.js:38:53)
  at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
  at /Users/xyx/Desktop/Git/question-authoring-platform/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/generate.js:7:71
  at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at __awaiter (/Users/xyx/Desktop/Git/question-authoring-platform/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/generate.js:3:12)
  at GenerateCommand.initialize (/Users/xyx/Desktop/Git/question-authoring-platform/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/generate.js:30:16)
```

Even I tried for other commands for `myTable` and `matNavbar`

```
ng generate @angular/material:materialNavbar --name matNavbar
ng generate @angular/material:materialTable --name myTable
```

The same error happened with the above two commands. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Investigation turns out that the commands aliases for generation of `materialShell`, `materialDashboard`, `materialNav` and `materialTable` were removed from `schematics/collection.json` of `@angular/material`. Rather while using it you can only use kebab case form of them.

```
materialShell => material-shell
materialDashboard => material-dashboard
materialNav => material-nav
materialTable => material-table
```

[**Commit Here**](https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/11839/files)

So rather than using older command like this

```
ng generate @angular/material:materialNav --name my-navbar
```

use

```
ng generate @angular/material:material-nav --name my-navbar
```

Answer (score 6):

In the official documentation

Install Schematics

```
ng add @angular/material
```

Generator Schematics

Navigation Schematic

```
ng generate @angular/material:material-nav --name <component-name>
```

Dashboard Schematic

```
ng generate @angular/material:material-dashboard --name <component-name>
```

Table Schematic

```
ng generate @angular/material:material-table --name <component-name>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can install it using:
`ng generate @angular/material:dashboard --name myDashboard`

For other components it will be:
`ng generate @angular/material:nav --name myNav`
`ng generate @angular/material:table --name myTable`

Info about other s
`/node_modules/@angular/material/schematics/collection.json`